# How to query where-greater-than then order it by another document value in firestore?

Tags: android, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query in firestore where I want to get the products where the stocks are greater than zero then order it by index. So I tried like this:

```
Query query = db.collection("Products").whereGreaterThan("productStock", 0)
                .orderBy("productStock").orderBy("index", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

In the documentation of Firesbase Firestore, they said

> However, if you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field:

But it won't work. The only working was the `orderby("productStock")` and 
the `.orderBy("index", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);` isn't working.

I just want to know if this kind of method is possible? if not,
is there any way to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: Did you define a custom composite index on `productStock`+`index`? If not, check your logcat output, which should contain an error message with a direct link to the console page where you create it. That link will have the correct values already filled in, so you only have to open the link, and click the button.

Comment: Yes, I already define it. But still not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean in this case? Are you getting an error? Are the results in a different order from what you expect (and if so, what order)? Is there anything possibly related showing in your logcat output when the query executes?

Comment: When I said "not working" it means that the result is not what am I expecting, because the result that was showing was the `.orderby("productStock")` and not the `.orderBy("index", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);`.

Comment: The results will first be ordered by `productStock`. That is what your query specifies, and must specify. If you want them to primarily be sorted on the second field, you will have to reorder them client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get a range of matching documents that are primarily filtered on another field. If you need that functionality, use the query to limit the number of documents, and re-order them client-side.